# ¿Por que no funciona el boton para desplegar el menu en laravel mix?

Tags: laravel-mix, collapse

No funciona el boton despegable en laravel-mix por lo que veo el codigo esta bien. como se puede corroborar en nav.blade.php para solucionar anteriormente cambie la version de node a la version 14.0.0 al actualizarla funciono. hice cambios en el layout.blade agregando el footer y el contenedor. y ya no funciona. cuando actualice

aqui las dependencias en el package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.19",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.34.0",
        "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.13",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.13"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2"
    }
}
```

nav.blade.php    aqui el código para el botón despegable

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg bg-white shadow-sm">

    <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{route(('home'))}}">
        {{config('app.name')}}
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{‌{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

    <ul class="nav nav-pills" >
        <li class=" nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link {{setActive('home')}}" href="{{route('home')}}">@lang('home') </a>
        </li>
        <li class=" nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link {{setActive('abouts')}}" href="{{route('abouts')}}">@lang('About')</a>
        </li>
        <li class=" nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link {{setActive('projects.*')}}" href="{{route('projects.index')}}">@lang('Projects')</a>
        </li>
        <li class=" nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link {{setActive('contactos')}}" href="{{route('contactos')}}">@lang('Contact')</a>
        </li>
        @guest
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link {{setActive('login')}}" href="{{route('login')}}">Login</a>
        </li>
        @else
            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"> Cerrar Sesion</a>
            </li>
        @endguest
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
    @csrf
</form>
```

layout.blade.php  aquí los códigos que agregue antes de que no funcione dicho botón

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title> @yield('title','DYF')</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{mix('/css/app.css')}}">
 <script src="{{mix('/js/app.js')}}" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
    <header>
        @include('partials.nav')
        @include('partials.session-status')
    </header>
    <main>
        @yield('content')
    </main>
<footer>
    {{config('app.name')}} | Copyright @ {{date('y')}}
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código escrito manualmente, no en imágenes por favor. Eso facilita mucho el que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Supongo que será una característica del javascript de bootstrap. Veo que está en las dependencias del package.json, pero.. ¿Cómo implementas bootstrap en tu proyecto?

Comment: bootstrap ya esta implementa cuando ejecuto yarn o npm install donde se guarda las dependencias. El tema es que anteriormente el boton si funcionaba. solo agregeue el codigo en el  layout.blade.php actualice. pws ya no funciona

Comment: No del todo, cuando ejecutas yarn o npm install se descargará en los node_modules, pero en algún lado tendrías que hacer `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';` o `require('bootstrap');` además de popper y jquery. [Aquí](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c4a7a7bc9cdccd00d6fdda8846d1660a0608d7ef/resources/js/bootstrap.js#L13) puedes ver un ejemplo.

Comment: muchas gracias. por el aporte. de echo si esta el import para bootstrap. en el app.js ''' 
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
'''